# canvas.toDataURL() doesn't return image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am expecting to return image Mirror-ed and it returns black image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
  <!--PLACE WHERE IMAGE MUST BE PUT ANFTER MIRROR-->
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000" style="background:#0094ff"></canvas>
  <!--Canvas Element-->
  <script>
    /*Creating Canvas*/
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

     // translate context to center of canvas
    context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    /*center the image*/

     // flip context horizontally
    context.scale(-1, 1); /*mirror image*/


    var imageObj = new Image();
    /*creating image object*/
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

    imageObj.onload = function() {

      context.drawImage(imageObj, -imageObj.width / 2, -imageObj.height / 2);
      /* draw and center the image*/
      context.restore();
      context.save();
    };
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    /* canvas to url  */
    document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
     // using url as source for img with id canvasImg
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two issues here.

1.) You are converting canvas to dataURL even before canvas has been drawn.
Add a delay to see the result.

```
setTimeout(function(){
          var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
          console.log(dataURL);
          /* canvas to url  */
          document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
           // using url as source for img with id canvasImg
    },2000);
```

2.) You are loading image from different server, so it will raise security issue. See error in your console. "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported."

Now, to avoid this error you can download the image to your local machine. Change image path to point where you stored your image on local machine. This will work.

Comment: The proper place would be  in the `load` callback, not in a timeout.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! :)

Comment: True. Also you  can use .complete property, but it might not work with all browsers(specially firefox).

Comment: A correction: You can deliver the image from any server you desire as long as that server is in the same domain as the webpage.